# why apt-get cannot install any application?

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, aptitude

when trying to install application using apt-get, I always get

`/bin/sh: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: not found`

for example:

```
$sudo apt-get install libssl-dev  
[sudo] password for camino:   
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
 ....

Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y  
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!  
  libssl-dev libssl0.9.8  
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y  


/bin/sh: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: not found  
Setting up debconf (1.5.35+maemo3+0m6) ...  
exec: 19: /usr/share/debconf/frontend: not found  
dpkg: error processing debconf (--configure):    
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 debconf  


$sudo dpkg-reconfigure libssl-dev  
sudo: unable to execute /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: No such file or directory  

$ls /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure  
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure  

$which dpkg-reconfigure  
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure  

$dpkg-reconfigure  
bash: /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: /usr/bin/perl.real: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What the heck did you do to get your system into this state?  There are protections against uninstalling core system packages.

Comment: sorry,I cannot remember whether I have deleted something or not

Comment: @Camino Please do not add the solution into your question. Write a separate answer or add it as a comment to the answer you marked as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system is so broken that I will recommend a fresh installation.

Rationale:  If these very broken things are just the tip of the iceberg then this system will give you a LOT of problems in time to come.  Get it in a known state - the easiest way to do so is with a fresh install.

(and then don't do the things you did, again).

Comment: If somebody knowledgeable had direct access to the machine in question, they might be able to `wget` and `ar` and `tar` (or maybe `dpkg-deb` still works, who knows) the system back into a usable state, but over SU… the easiest thing to do is almost certainly reinstall.

Comment: @ephemient - how would you determine when you are done fixing things?

Answer (score 2):

> bash: /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure:
>   /usr/bin/perl.real: bad interpreter:
>   No such file or directory

**perl.real**? What the heck? Something or someone has modified your `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure` to contain a wrong path to Perl.

Edit the `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure` with your favourite text editor and sudo, for example `sudo nano -w /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure` and change the beginning of the file from

`#!/usr/bin/perl.real -w`

to

`#!/usr/bin/perl -w`

Comment: thank you!,the perl issue has been fixed,but the apt-get still can not work

Comment: ... and in what way it fails? Please update your original question and be more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

i resolved this using
`sudo apt install --reinstall po-debconf`
et voilà, after that command i can install new programms

(Ubuntu 14.04 32bit - running on Eee PC 1000HE)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect their may be something wrong with apt or dpkg-config or possible your bash session.

Try running this because it probably can't hurt

```
sudo su -      (this lets you become root and uses its settings)

apt-get update && sudo apt-get update && sudo aptitude full-upgrade

exit           (get out of root)
```

The two apt-get updates are intentional. If there is a problem with one, the second run may fix the first run. You can also replace `full-upgrade` with `safe-upgrade` if you don't want to clean unused packages.

Comment: I tried this, and got an error: **sudo: aptitude: command not found**

Answer (score 0):

Unless you only messed up your PATH variable, you may have somehow deleted an important program.

-What does your $PATH variable say?
-Have you deleted any directories since apt-get has last worked?

Comment: $echo $PATH  
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo aptitude remove` -> `sudo aptitude update` -->  and then try to intall again `sudo aptitude install libssl-dev` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libssl-dev`

Comment: $sudo dpkg-reconfigure libssl-dev
sudo: unable to execute /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: No such file or directory

but in fact /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure do exist
$ls /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all .

**the issue has been fixed ,**

I use dpkg to show info about debconf

```
$dpkg -l |grep debconf

ri  debconf        1.5.35+maemo3+0m6               Debian configuration management system  
ii  debconf-i18n   1.5.35+maemo3+0m6       full internationalization support for debcon   
ii  po-debconf     1.0.16                      tool for managing templates file translation  
ii  ssl-cert       1.0.23ubuntu2             simple debconf wrapper for OpenSSL
```

it is very strange that debconf  is maemo ,
so I copy debconf and frontend from other's ubuntu machine,
it works now!
but dpkg -l still show it was maemo.

Thanks

Comment: What is **frontend**?